# How to .wrap in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery `.wrap` documentation says:

> This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element.

So if I supply:

```
<div><div></div></div>
```

The element will be wrapped as:

```
<div><div>$(this)</div></div>
```

How to force jQuery to wrap like this:

```
<div>$(this)<div></div></div>
```

Comment: `$(this).wrap('<div/>').next($('<div/>'))`

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can `wrap()` the original element, then use `parent().append()` to create another sibling to it, like this:

```
$(this).wrap('<div />').parent().append('<div />');
```

Alternatively, you can skip the `parent().append()` and use just `after()` instead, depending on your exact requirements:

```
$(this).wrap('<div />').after('<div />');
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0cnshgo9/)

Comment: I have used that as workaround. It seems ugly. I expect `.wrap` callback may set sharp place for wrapped content.